# invalid_referer syntax for if in nginx

Tags: nginx, referer, nginx-config

I use this in my **nginx.conf** where **${WWW_URL}** is variable with my web app url

```
location ~* \.(jpg|png)$ {
    valid_referers none blocked www.${WWW_URL} ${WWW_URL};

    if ($invalid_referer) { # line 63
        return 403;
    }
}
```

But when I start nginx I got

> [emerg] invalid condition ")" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63

I try to change the indent, delete space ... what is the issue on this if statement ?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that `valid_referrers` accepts variables, strings containing `{}` probably need to be enclosed between single or double quotes.

Comment: I use `envsubst` to replace my vars by env variables. And if I hard code my url instead I'm the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`envsubst` is probably removing `$invalid_referer` from `if ($invalid_referer) {`

`nginx: [emerg] invalid condition ")" in /etc/nginx...` is the error returned for empty brackets in an `if` condition

Comment: In my docker-compose I explicitly give the var `/bin/bash -c "envsubst $$WWW_URL < /etc/nginx/mysite.template > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"`